# How do I enable PVP in creative mode NMS?

Tags: no-mans-sky

My friends and I wish to have a No Man's Sky PVP battle, using creative mode to get our weapons, tools, and upgrades. Although, once we got into space and got ready, our shots did no damage to each other. We then landed on the ground, and whipped out our boltcasters, and yet no damage either.
Is there a way to make PVP do damage, but still have our stuff from creative mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, unfortunately. Creation mode is designed for exploration and building, not combat. Therefore, you do not take any damage in this mode.

> The player is allowed to indulge their creativity and construction skills, **with unlimited health and resources**, and zero building costs.
> <sub>[Source](https://nomanssky.fandom.com/wiki/Game_mode#Creative_mode)</sub>

This is also discussed and confirmed on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/l0tysx/creative_mode_any_way_to_add_health_damage/) and [Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/275850/discussions/0/2270319347591791359/). If you are playing on PC, one user on Steam suggested to try and change the game mode using a save editor, but there were no additional comments regarding if this worked on not. However, not sure if this would fit your desire, as it would no longer be considered creation mode.